# Is there way to analyze App Engine HTTP logs?

Tags: google-app-engine, log-analysis

I mean getting comprehensive stats like AWSStats provides at other hosters, showing traffic stats by bots, etc. which Google Analytics does not provide (because not all bots execute Javascript)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, by default there isn't a graph that shows the information regarding bot traffic